# Angular2 Shared Module

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have a question. I have some components that I want to be able to added all over my application. I don't to load all this components from the beggining but on demand (lazy loading).

For example I have this component  that I want to add only in some of pages. but not on load.

Is shared module the right place? Do I have to load it from the app.module?

Answer (score 0):

If you have components that re-used multiple times, that's certainly should go to the Shared Module. Unless if it is service, service shouldn't be in the Shared module.